# RecyclerView slide automatically skips the header

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I used to add the viewtype way to add a header for RecycleView, but the interface will directly skip header refresh, but if the decline, the header will still be displayed, but the refresh will skip this line, which is caused by it

This is the code for the onCreateViewHolder () method in the adapter

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
        View headerView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header_online, parent, false);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        headerView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        return new OnlineHeaderHolder(headerView, context);
    } else if (viewType == TYPE_STAR) {
        View starView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_online_star, parent, false);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        starView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        return new OnlineStarViewHolder(starView, context);
    } else {
        View normalView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_online, parent, false);
        return new OnlineListHolder(normalView, context);
    }
}
```

Here's the header layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/xx"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimens_xh_15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimens_xh_15dp"
        android:text="@string/latest_active"
        android:textColor="@color/xx"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/xx"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/xx"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/xx"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/xx"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/xx"
        android:src="@mipmap/xx" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/xx"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="xx"
        android:layout_marginRight="xx"
        android:src="@mipmap/xx" />

</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/xx" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here with xx removed some irrelevant information

Here's my onBindViewHolder () method
I use a model that contains all the data, there is a "type" attribute in the model to distinguish between different types

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    OnlineNewAdaper.OnlineModel onlineModel = modelList.get(position);
    switch (onlineModel.getType()) {
        case TYPE_HEADER:
            ((OnlineHeaderHolder) holder).setData(onlineModel);
            ((OnlineHeaderHolder) holder).setOnlineSelectListener(listener);
            break;
        case TYPE_STAR:
            ((OnlineStarViewHolder) holder).setData(onlineModel);
            break;
        case TYPE_NORMAL:
            ((OnlineListHolder) holder).setData(onlineModel, mServerTime);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is OnlineHeaderHolder code:

```
public class OnlineHeaderHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

public OnlineHeaderHolder(View itemView, Context context) {
    super(itemView);
    this.context = context;

    ViewHelper.inject((ViewGroup) itemView, this);
}

public void setData(OnlineNewAdaper.OnlineModel data) {
    if (data.getType() != TYPE_HEADER) {
        return;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You know that `onCreateViewHolder` is not for refreshing, right? So please show your `onBindViewHolder` and `getItemViewType` methods.

Comment: I'm sorry, I showed too little code, and now I've done it

Comment: How do you refresh? Asking because `setData` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Here is a fixed layout, it can be understood as no data refresh

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying, that you are not refreshing data at any point? What is your problem then?

Comment: When I enter this interface, it will automatically slide to the head below the location.
I'm sorry, maybe I do not know what I'm saying. The words I made were generated by Google Translate

Answer (score 1):

You can try with following attribute at the root container.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

That will disable focusability for its descendant views. You have other two option value for use : `afterDescendant`   & `beforeDescendant`.